# How can i keep this dropdown menu visibile while hovered?

Tags: jquery, css

I built a dropdown menu using a script posted by another stack user, but now im having trouble keeping it visible when i mouse over it.
Here is the website:

```
http://79.24.150.216/
```

And you can try hovering "INFO" and then try and hover the menu that displays, and you will see it wont stay visible.

You can find the css at:

```
http://79.24.150.216/css/main.css
```

And this is the js snippet used:

```
$('nav li').on('mouseenter mouseleave hover',function( e ){
$('#'+$(this).data('open'))[e.type=='mouseenter'?'slideDown':'slideUp'](); });
```

Thank you in advance for your precious help.

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML and CSS *here*, otherwise the question becomes nonsensical or useless in future, when the resources are moved or the problem is fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('nav li').on('mouseenter click hover',function( e ){
        var value = $(this).attr('data-open');
        $('#'+value).slideDown();     
    });

    $('#subnav ul li').on('mouseleave', function(e){
        var menu = $(this).parent().parent().parent().attr('id');
        $('#'+menu).slideUp();
    });
});
```

hope it helps.

Suggestion: You can defined the submenu with info-submenu so you can dynamically get the right div to load over top menus.

Comment: This works, but it looses the "slide" animation it has now (wich i rather liked, if its possible to keep) and it stays active for all nav li's, not only INFO. Or was that what the suggestion is about?

Comment: Here is your solution at work: `http://79.24.150.216/test/`
*Also, it only clears when you mouse over the main content, not if you mouse over the top or the sides.

Comment: change the method show() to slideDown() and hide with SlideUp(); for animation.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed the animation, but as you can see here `http://79.24.150.216/test/` the tab stays active for all `nav li`'s and only slides up when you mouse over directly the content, not if you mouse over the banner for example.

Comment: I already edit for dynamically load the submenu based on top selection. if you think any answer on the page helps in you query then you should vote! :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding `#subnav` to the elements used for the hover function `$('nav li, #subnav')`?

Comment: I tried it now, its currently like that on the address i provided, but nothing changed.

Comment: I'd also recommend using `.stop(true)` after `$('nav li')` as when you quickly hover on and off of it multiple times it will take a while to catch up. Doing this will allow it to run only the once.

Comment: Haha i was getting irritated so i called it that. Anyway yes that was annoying me, but unfortunately putting that stop didnt help much (i inserted it like this `$('nav li').stop(true).on('mouseen...` wich i suppose is correct) and it didnt work, you can check yourself at the same address.
Oh, and also #bollocks didnt work, its just a div to set the grey colour across the whole thing, and not just the navi.

Answer (score 1):

Your hover is only working on the LI element so once you hover away from that you're losing the hover and the subnav is closing.

you could try making two classes
    .default-class { display: none }
    .show { display: block }

then try 
    $('nav li').on('hover click', function() { $('.subnav').addClass('show'); })

then to hide do a mouse leave event on the subnav (.removeClass('show');
and you could also make hovering over any of the other li elements make the subnav hide also.

Comment: I tried that, and aside from the fact i cant seem able to get it to work (im a noobie), i think that would loose the smooth "sliding" animation i was kind of counting to keep?

Comment: You can use modernizr to check for animation support if they are supported use css3 if not use jquery .animate.